# Get focus on input form fields via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to get focus on input text fields via classic Javascript | jQuery:

```
    $('#exampleInputEmail1').focus();
```

or

```
    document.getElementById('exampleInputEmail1').focus();
```

You can test it directly on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms .

FYI: I have already opened an issue on GitHub ( [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14424) ) about this question but in the meantime I'd ask if there is someone that already known a solution or a workaround.

Thank you.

max

Comment: The way you're using the console window is making your test invalid.  Try this: `setTimeout(function(){$('#exampleInputEmail1').eq(0).focus();}, 3000);` in the console window but make sure that you click back into the form before that 3 seconds expires.  In other words, make sure the form has focus rather than the console.  Then you'll see the desired control receive the focus.

Comment: The console window is preventing focus on the input. This has nothing to do with javascript...

Comment: yes, I try it and it works! But now the question is: why it doesn't work in the way I used?
@bastos.sergio: preventing? Why? For security reasons?

Comment: I think it's just the way the console window works... It prevents javascript from moving focus away from it.

Comment: You could also do something like this `alert('bring focus to window');$('#exampleInputEmail1').focus();` The alert dialog is there to break you out of the console command window...